# @ComponentScan for external dependency package is not working in 2.1.x at the time of building the jar and running that jar

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm facing an issuing while using the spring boot 2.1.x.RELEASE as it is not scanning the basepackages in component scan but It is working perfectly fine in 2.0.x.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.base*", "com.app.child.*" })
```

When creating a build using

```
mvn clean package
```

It's jar has been created but when running the jar it is not loading the beans from the base external repository.

```
java -jar child.jar
```

Exception:

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization 
- cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Failed to parse configuration class
```

[com.app.child.UserApiApplication]; 
    nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    class path resource [com/app/base/service/BaseService.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I am adding base.jar in the lib/base.jar of the child project. Following is the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>base</artifactId>
  <version>0.2</version>
</dependency>
<repository>
  <id>myRepo</id>
  <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
</repository>
```

For deploy base.jar into my local repository

```
 mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.app -DartifactId=base-Dversion=0.2 -Durl=file:./myRepo -DrepositoryId=myRepo -DupdateReleaseInfo=true -Dfile=lib/base-0.2.jar
```

The component scan is well working when I run the application from STS. But when I am creating build and trying to run the jar It is throwing error.

I have also exploded the child.jar using

```
jar -tf child.jar
```

base.jar was there in the list.

Comment: The contents of base.jar need to be part of your child.jar, not the jar itself.

Comment: @Neo can't be part of child.jar we have a requirement where we need to explicitly seperate out the base.jar so that it can be reuseable to other child.jar as well.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to say what exactly is the issue.
First of all for you can use ComponentScan like this

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.base", "com.app.child" })
```

See [Spring Framework ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#basePackages--)

Next to it, it looks like that you're trying to run a java file which is not a fat jar or you're not setting the expecting classes into your classpath.

you can add this class by adding a classpath to your call.

```
java -cp <path/to/base.jar> -jar child.jar
```

Give it a try. If this is working, at least you have a hint, that you base.jar isn't loaded correctly.

Comment: I have tried all the steps it is still not working. Thanks @Manuel for the help. I don't know why it is working in spring 2.0.x but not in spring 2.1.x. I have also read a release document of spring 2.1.x In which they have specified the overriding of beans property But I am not sure what other changes they have made in this release.

Comment: Do you have some source code to share, that i can give it a try?

Comment: https://github.com/mrkunal/orion.git I have pushed two branches. Please take a look I have also added the steps to reproduce in the readme.

Comment: I got it running, but that's a bit weird, i have to say. From the base project i removed the build node in the pom.xml. In the child node i removed the plugin maven-install-plugin, then i started the app like i answered and it worked for me. I can see the output ###App Config From Base called### when im running the child app. Looks like it is a configuration issue with the plugins.

Comment: @Thanks Manuel for debugging. Actually that was the issue with the repackage module. As of 2.1.x the repackage execution has an identifier. We are adding a second repackage so  end up with two fat jars. I have merged the fix in the repo url. Thanks to https://github.com/snicoll.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.1.x the repackage execution has an identifier. we are adding a second repackage so  end up with two fat jars.

```
                <executions>
                    <execution><!-- 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals> -->
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```